# How to read console inner values of console log

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, primevue

I have been able to read the outer Values from console log but i am getting errors in IDE whenever i try to read inner values.

when i do console.log(Primevue.name), i get "Button" as an output.

But when i do console.log(Primevue.props), i am getting errors. How to get props object values?

**My Console Output:**

[image: Console log errors]

**My code:**

```
<template>
  <PrimeButton />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue"
import PrimeButton from "primevue/button"



const Component = defineComponent({

     components: { PrimeButton },
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(PrimeButton)
  },
})

export default Component
</script>
```

**I am using this library: [Primevue](https://primefaces.org/primevue/showcase/#/setup)**

Comment: What error do you get when you do `console.log(Primevue.props)` ?

Comment: Property 'props' does not exist on type 'typeof Button'. I am getting right output but it shows error in IDE